# realloc() on array of structs gives invalid next size

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have this function. As you can see, everything is being done in the function, I'm not allocating in the main and then passing anything to it (I'll only return the pointer to the array once the function is done). The function in itself (with a fixed size for the array) works, but the realloc fails.

```
struct database *parse() {

    int i = 0;
    int n = 1;

    FILE *dbase = (fopen(PATH, "r"));
    if (dbase == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, ERRORE_APERTURA);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct database *database_array =  calloc(20*n, sizeof(struct database));
    if (database_array == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Impossibile allocare memoria\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (feof(dbase) == 0) {
        fscanf(dbase, "%[^:]:%[^:]:\n", database_array[i].user, database_array[i].password);
        database_array[i].iswritten = 1;
        i++;
        if (i > 20*n) {
            n++;
            struct database *new_database_array = realloc(database_array, sizeof(struct database)*(20*n));
            database_array = new_database_array;
        }
    }
    database_array[++i].iswritten = 0;

    fclose(dbase);  
    return database_array;
}
```

I tried reading other explanations, but I can't understand what's wrong here.

The array I allocated with calloc is initially 20. then, when it's filled, I want it to double in size, so I use n, which will be 2, by 20, so 40.

The frustrating thing is that I tried reallocating an array of struct with a simpler program, and doing THE SAME THING works without any problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct prova  {

    int a;

    int b[10];
};


int main() {

    struct prova* array_struct = calloc(10, sizeof(struct prova));

    array_struct[0].a = 2;

    struct prova* tmp = realloc(array_struct, sizeof(struct prova) * 20);

    free(array_struct);
    array_struct = tmp;

    array_struct[1].b[1] = 3;

    printf("a = %d", array_struct[0].a);
    printf("b = %d\n", array_struct[1].b[1]);

    return 0;   
}
```

What am I not seeing? (Please nevermind the fact that I'm not checking if realloc returns NULL, I'll add that later)

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: If you `realloc`, do not `free` the original pointer.

Comment: `struct prova* tmp = realloc (array_struct, sizeof *tmp * 20);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin How should I do that for the function? sizeof(new_database_array)*40 doesn't work

Comment: Note: `while (feof(dbase) == 0)` does not check the stream for `EOF`, but only an internal flag which has been set by a former reading function! You still have to check the results of all reading functions explicitly; do not rely on `feof`!

Comment: @Paul You should `free` the re-alloced block at the end of course. But what happening currently it is undefined behavior. (And if `realloc` returned the same pointer as its argument, it is freed before using).

Comment: if one example works and the other doesn't then they are not the same things.

Comment: @RichardChambers Well I'm passing to realloc() the previous pointer I allocated and the size of the struct by the number I want in both cases... If there is a difference, I can't see it, that's why I asked

Comment: `database_array[++i].iswritten = 0` will invoke *undefined behavior* if your loop terminated on an exact multiple of  `n` enries. The test for `if (i > 20*n)` should be `if (i == 20*n)`. Regardless, this isn't an interactive debugging site, and the changes you've made to your posted code now make the most-upticked comment above and sole answer below meaningless, which is ill-advised.

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry, I was trying to remove other error to help focus on the main one

Comment: @WhozCraig the test you pointed out was the culprit, thank you very much. I must have changed that by mistake.

Comment: @WhozCraig Following your other suggestion, I made it so that the allocation is made on (20*n+1), this should avoid the undefined behavior.

Comment: @Paul just changing the if-condition as i described should take care of it. There is no reason to refigure math elsewhere.

Comment: @WhozCraig While in the case of the calloc alone this works, I found that if the realloc is exectuted and I do end up on the exact number of allocated structs (say, 20x2), in the output of the program (where I print the values of the structs) I'll have an extra struct which has ?? symbols in it. Allocating 20x2+1 fixes this.

Comment: @Paul "Fixes" is somewhat nebulous. I'm just telling you. The problem of UB I mentioned would be addressed by changing that if-condition *only*. Nothing else would need be done (besides fixing the problem David pointed out in his answer, which *seriously* deserves an uptick). What you do with that is up to you.

Comment: @WhozCraig I obviously want to do what's best. I'll check what's happening exactly when I print the array (I think I know what is happening). I do not understand what DavidCRanking is point out honestly...

Answer (score 2):

```
struct database *new_database_array = realloc(database_array, sizeof(struct database)*(20*n));
free(database_array);
```

You can't both reallocate something and deallocate it. You can do either, but once you've done either, the previous allocation no longer exists, so you can't do the other.

After the first line of code above, the value of `database_array` should not be used anymore because it may not be valid.

Comment: I added the free() just to see if it worked. It doesn't even without it.

Comment: @Paul It's entirely possible you have more than one bug. But you have to fix the most serious ones first, and that one's catastrophic. (You have that same bug in `main` too. You can't really even analyze the code while it has a bug that serious.)

Comment: I tested the program and it does work. I mean, if there are any bugs I can't see them. If I don't realloc the array it works perfectly (but I'm stuck with a set size for the array). If I try to reallocate it, it breaks. So I think the problem is in that call.